# ScatterPlot doens't work properly - dots isn't connected

Tags: ios, charts, frameworks, core-plot, scatter-plot

I am developing a project using Core-Plot with Objective-C. The client asks to create a line chart (using Scatter Plot for this) where plots the number of ocurrencies x the time.

Well, after study for almost a week, this isn't working. My dots aren't connected and I don't know why.

[image: Plots doesn't work]

This blue line should've been connected, since it is one plot.

Here is my code:

```
-(void)renderInLayer:(CPTGraphHostingView *)layerHostingView withTheme:(CPTTheme *)theme animated:(BOOL)animated{
CPTGraph *graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];
[self addGraph:graph toHostingView:layerHostingView];
[self applyTheme:theme toGraph:graph withDefault:[CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTDarkGradientTheme]];

graph.paddingTop = 20.0;
graph.paddingRight = 20.0;
graph.paddingLeft = 20.0;

CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;
plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = YES;
plotSpace.delegate              = self;

CPTMutableLineStyle *axesLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
axesLineStyle.lineWidth            = 1.0f;
axesLineStyle.miterLimit           = 1.0f;
axesLineStyle.lineColor            = [CPTColor grayColor];

CPTTextStyle *labelTextStyle = [CPTTextStyle textStyleWithAttributes:@{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName: BoardGraphValueColor, NSFontAttributeName: BoardGraphValueFont}];

CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;
NSNumberFormatter * axisFormat = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[axisFormat setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterNoStyle];
CPTXYAxis *x          = axisSet.xAxis;{
    x.visibleRange                  = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:@(-1.0) length:@(100)];
    x.labelingPolicy                = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic;
    x.majorIntervalLength           = @2;
    x.minorTicksPerInterval         = 1;
    x.majorTickLineStyle            = axesLineStyle;
    x.minorTickLineStyle            = axesLineStyle;
    x.axisLineStyle                 = axesLineStyle;

    x.plotSpace                     = plotSpace;
    x.labelTextStyle                = labelTextStyle;
    x.labelFormatter                = axisFormat;
    x.labelOffset                   = 5.0;
}

CPTXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;{
    y.visibleRange   = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:@(-1.0) length:@(200)];
    y.labelingPolicy                = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic;
    y.majorIntervalLength           = @30;
    y.minorTicksPerInterval         = 6;
    y.majorTickLineStyle            = axesLineStyle;
    y.minorTickLineStyle            = axesLineStyle;
    y.axisLineStyle                 = axesLineStyle;

    y.plotSpace                     = plotSpace;
    y.labelTextStyle                = labelTextStyle;
    y.labelFormatter                = axisFormat;
    y.labelOffset                   = 5.0;
}

graph.axisSet.axes = @[x, y];

CPTMutableLineStyle *lineStyle = [[CPTMutableLineStyle alloc] init];
lineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0;

CPTScatterPlot *scatterLinePlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
scatterLinePlot.areaBaseValue = @(0.0);

scatterLinePlot.identifier = @(1);
scatterLinePlot.title = @"Title";

lineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor blueColor];
scatterLinePlot.dataLineStyle = lineStyle;
scatterLinePlot.histogramOption = self.histogramOption;

scatterLinePlot.areaBaseValue = @(0);

scatterLinePlot.delegate                        = self;
scatterLinePlot.plotSymbolMarginForHitDetection = 5.0;
scatterLinePlot.dataSource = self;

[graph addPlot:scatterLinePlot];

CPTPlotRange *globalYRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:@0.0
                                                          length:@12.0];
plotSpace.globalYRange = globalYRange;

[plotSpace scaleToFitEntirePlots:[graph allPlots]];}
```

This is the code for create just **one plot**, but I need to create **six**. I did a loop but it is working that way too.

Here's the datasource:

```
-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(nonnull CPTPlot *)plot{
return [self.plotData objectAtIndex:0].count;}

-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(nonnull CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index{
NSNumber *num = nil;
NSString *key;
NSArray *currentDataPoint;

NSString *plotIdentifier = (NSString *)plot.identifier;

if ([plotIdentifier isEqual:@(1)]){
    currentDataPoint = [self.plotData objectAtIndex:0];
} else if ([plotIdentifier isEqual:@(2)]){
    currentDataPoint = [self.plotData objectAtIndex:1];
} else if ([plotIdentifier isEqual:@(3)]){
    currentDataPoint = [self.plotData objectAtIndex:2];
} else if ([plotIdentifier isEqual:@(4)]){
    currentDataPoint = [self.plotData objectAtIndex:3];
} else if ([plotIdentifier isEqual:@(5)]){
    currentDataPoint = [self.plotData objectAtIndex:4];
} else if ([plotIdentifier isEqual:@(6)]){
    currentDataPoint = [self.plotData objectAtIndex:5];
}

if (fieldEnum == CPTScatterPlotFieldX) {

    return @(index);

} else if (fieldEnum == CPTScatterPlotFieldY) {

    key = @"count";
    int number = [[[currentDataPoint objectAtIndex:index] valueForKey:key] intValue];
    NSLog(@"Y value for index %lu is %d", index, number);
    num = [[currentDataPoint objectAtIndex:index] valueForKey:key];
    return num;}

return num;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

PS: Well, another bug is the color of the bar chart. Each of this should have a different color, but it doesn't work too. The colors provided is that for the legends.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To change the bar color for each bar, implement the `-barFillForBarPlot:recordIndex:` method in the datasource and return the correct fill for each index. You can also set the border line style for each bar (e.g., to use a different color) with the `-barLineStyleForBarPlot:recordIndex:` datasource method.

It looks like the data line is getting clipped outside the visible area. Make sure the plot data is available from the datasource when you call `-scaleToFitEntirePlots:`.

Comment: Thanks @Eric Skroch, the problem with the lines were the `globalYrange` from the graph. Changed it and worked.

About the bars, I'm using this:
`[CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor colorWithCGColor:[UIColor colorWithHexString:color].CGColor]]` and doens't work. (the variable color has a hex value) 
When I change to, i.e., `[CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor redColor]]`, all my bars change to Red.

Am I doing something wrong? 
Thanks again!

Comment: Make sure that `-colorWithHexString:` is returning a valid color.

Comment: It is! It returning the colors of the legends at the bottom of the picture.

@Eric Skroch, if you can help me: in the scatter plot I'm trying to select a area, but I can't understand the `plotAreaWasSelected:`. Is this method that I use to it?

Comment: Look at the *DropPlot* example app included with Core Plot. It shows how to select a rectangular area on the graph and zoom in. It's a Mac app so you'll probably need to make some adjustments to use it on iOS. It includes a `.csv` data file with plot data you can use for a demo.

Comment: Eric, hello!
I've fixed almost all my issues by persistence. If anything else appears I'll open another question.
Thanks!